Nuxt3 calling external api got cors error
hi i am using axios to call external api and i keep getting cors error right now
my nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  srcDir: 'frontend/',
  buildDir: 'frontend/.nuxt',
  modules: [
    [
      '@pinia/nuxt',
      {
        autoImports: ['defineStore'],
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: ['~/plugins/axios.js', '~/plugins/aos.js'],

  nitro: {
        devProxy: {
            '/api/': {
                target: process.env.API_URL,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    }
});


my axios.js
import axios from 'axios';
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? process.env.API_BASE_URL
        : process.env.API_URL;

    const token = 'your_bearer_token_here';

    // Create Axios instance
    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL,
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    });

    // Provide Axios instance globally
    nuxtApp.provide('axios', api);
});


i am not sure which step i am doing wrong coz i try call the api in postman and its work
